# Erron during R update from 3.4.4 to 4.2.2 : NextMethod('predict') : No method to invoke

Tags: r, zoo, quantmod

I have a big R project that was developed in version 3.4.4 . I have been tasked to upgrade the project to R version 4.2.2

First thing I notice is when I load my package I.e.
`devtools::load_all(.)` is I am getting below warning

```
Registered S3 method overwritten by 'quantmod':
method            from
as.zoo.data.frame zoo
```

Now coming to the error part

My code is using dyn library - predict method as below

As I understand , this predict.dyn will apply the predict method based on class of object, which is zoo in my case .

When I run this code in updated code (R 4.2 2) its throwing error

No method to invoke

So that's why I think because quantmod is overwriting methods of zoo package leading to this error as the code works fine ith old code (3.4.4)

Could anyone help me how to solve this issue .

**predict.dyn method definition**

```
function (object, newdata,...){

if (missing(newdata)) return(fitted(object))

class (object) <- setdiff(class (object), "dyn")

series <- attr (model.frame(object), "series")

.Class <- class (series [[1]])

NextMethod("predict")}
```

**Here value of .Class is zoo and value of class(object) is lm**

**In old code(3.4.4) next method('predict') was invoking predict.zoo**

I am not able to provide reproducible code , but let me know what do I need to provide to help solve this.

Please note ,, nothing has changed except for upgrades in package.

Comment: within the function `predict.dyn` are you using the method `NetxMethod()`?If so, what are the classes for the `object` used for prediction.

Comment: It appears that by attaching `quantmod`, the `as.zoo` method for data.frames gets overwritten.  The end result is likely that your object is not classed as `zoo` when it gets passed to `predict`. You might want to identify the class of `object`. That might give you some clues as to why the associated method is not found.

Comment: How do i make sure ```quantmod``` doesnt overwrite methods - as it was not doing in 3.4.4 version . or an idea how i deal with this

Comment: @Amit: `quantmod::as.zoo.data.frame()` existed before the zoo method and therefore has always overwritten it. So it's not obvious to me that it would cause this issue. See https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/commit/9343d9ad306e73d80120bee30bc325042dffe8cd. Further, `quantmod::as.zoo.data.frame()` throws a warning in quantmod >= 0.14.15, so you'd see a warning if it were being called. It's really hard to help without a reproducible example...